# how can I use string value as an argument?

Tags: java

for example:

```
>String str="index==1";  
>int index=1;  
>if(str)  
>       System.out.println("1");
```

what I mean is that the 'if' will use the value of "str" as an argument, and print "1".
I tryed to look for an answer and I didn't find
thank you very much!!

Comment: You can't do this - Java is a compiled language (even though the result of compilation is interpreted). Both `index` and `1` must be visible to the compiler at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is not able to do that kind of "eval"-functions, but there is a way to use javascript in java to return the result of an "eval" with "ScriptEngineManager":

```
  import javax.script.*;

  String str="index==1";
  int index = 1;

  try {

    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
    engine.put("index", index); //set  index as variable in js
    engine.put("str", str);//set str as variable in js

    Boolean result = (Boolean) engine.eval("result = eval(str)");  //eval function
    System.out.println("=>" + result);  //boolean as result
    if(result) System.out.println("1");

  } catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings save data as a sequence of chars. (an array of chars `char[] c;`) an if statements check for a boolean result. ie: `if(index == 1){...} //returns true`. However, the String str returns "index == 1" (a sequence of chars) not a boolean operator. Thats why `if(str)` won't work.